# Modify a "" class such that the toString method sorts the list of

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, tostring

Hey guys  im on my final step of this java proj and i think i know where to begin for this final piece but i am not sure how to.

i am supposed to:

Modify a class such that the toString method sorts the list of cows and the list of horses before iterating through the list. (an example of what i am supposed to do)

how would i be able to begin? the list of cows and horses are part of an arraylist.

would collections be involved? here is the code of my toString method.

```
  public String toString()
{

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    String output   =  "**************************************************\n"
                    +  "*                 List of Horses               *\n"
                    +  "**************************************************\n";

    for( Horse horse : listOfHorses )
    {
        output  += horse + "\n"
                +  "--------------------------------------------------\n";
    }


    output  +=  "\n**************************************************\n"
            +  "*                 List of Cows                *\n"
            +  "**************************************************\n";

    for( Cow cow : listOfCows )
    {
        output  += cow + "\nVisit Rate:\t\t\t" 
                + fmt.format( cow.getBillAmount() ) + "\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------------\n";
    }

    return output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can call [Collections.sort(listOfHorses)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) before the `for` loop on `listOfHorses`, and do the same with `listOfCows`.

Let me point out that -- homework aside -- it's a poor design idea for a `toString()` method to do a lot of computation, and an even worse design idea for it to have side effects (in this case, modifying the arraylists).

`toString()` ought to be free of side effects. When called by the debugger or a logging statement, those side effects will change what the program does and cause confusion.

Also, a loop that does `output += string` will be slower than building up the string in a `StringBuffer`. If the number of iterations is large, it will be *much* slower since the work it does will be O(N^2), that is, proportional to the number of strings squared rather than proportional to the number of strings.

Comment: thanks Jerry, so i would just have to add for example

Collections.sort(listOfCows);
Collections.sort(listOfPatients);
?

and yes I agree with the toString method comment, but it was in the description to do so:/

Comment: Yes, `Collections.sort(listOfCows)` will sort `listOfCows` in place, that is, reorder the elements of that ArrayList.

Comment: awesome i know it seemed like a simple question just didnt know it was that simple.

Comment: Glad to help. Do remember to "accept" the answer if it works.

Comment: @user3347866 Collections.sort() is a good approach to take. However you will have to override the `compareTo()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()` methods of your Cow class.